# How to call date() only once, then display it several times in different formats

Tags: php, date, variables

I have a page I use as a digital sign driven by a raspberry pi. The page displays the date and time as well as shows the current weather.

I'm calling the `date()` function three separate times. One is for determining if it's day or night for the weather icons, another is to display the time in larger numbers, and the last is to display the current date.

Is there a way I can just store `date()` in a single variable, then use it three different ways?

```
<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "10";
//header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
$bg = array(); // create an empty array
$directory = "images/"; //the directory all the images are in
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg"); //grab all of the images out of the directory with .jpg extention

foreach($images as $image) 
{
    $bg[] = $image;//populate the empty array with an array of all images in the directory folder
}

  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen

    $json_string="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=49.1985&lon=-113.302&appid=b29961db19171a5d4876c08caea9af0d&units=metric";
    $jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
    $obj = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    $now = date('U'); //get current time
    $temp = round($obj['main']['temp']);

  if($now > $obj['sys']['sunrise'] and $now < $obj['sys']['sunset']){
    $suffix = '-d';
  }else{
    $suffix = '-n';
  }

?>

<div id="todaysdatetime">
    <div id="todaystime">
    <span><?php echo(date("g:i A"));?></span>
    </div>
    <div id="todaysdate">
    <span><?php echo(date("l\, F j<\s\up>S</\s\up>"));echo ' &nbsp;&nbsp; <i class="owf owf-', $obj['weather'][0]['id'].$suffix, '"></i> ', $temp, '&deg;C'; ?></span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Three `date()` calls don't measurably slow your code down when you're actually doing an HTTP request in the meantime. Don't guess why your code is slow, benchmark it.

Comment: Benchmark or not, the idea that a few date calls could slow anything down by any noticeable amount is simply ludicrous ...

Comment: @CBroe Good to know. I'm just guessing at this point as to why it might be going slower on the pi than on my pc.

Comment: anyway you can't really do this, because what you pass to date() is the format you want to display it in. date() _is_ the function you call in order to format a date. So you can't store the result and use it again, because the result is a human-readable string which is hard to translate back into an internal date representation. What you're doing is already the easiest (and really, the only) way to do it.

Comment: It is slow in general, because you choose rather the wrong approach to begin with. _"The page displays the date and time as well as shows the current weather."_ - the "update frequency" you have in there, the commented meta-refresh, is 10 seconds - that's nonsense, weather doesn't change that quick, so you are needlessly hammering an API with unnecessary requests - bad for both sides. [...]

Comment: [...] If you want to update the display of date and time every 10 seconds, fine - do that using a _client-side_ counter (JavaScript.) Then choose a _reasonable_ refresh frequency in the meta tag, so that the page reloads and fresh data is fetched from the weather API - 5 minutes maybe if you want to be a stickler about it, maybe rather 15 or 30 as a common sense-y value ...

Comment: @ShemSeger posted, thanks. CBroe's explanation of the likely reason for your performance issues sounds pretty accurate to me, btw.

Comment: @CBroe I had that refresh commented out, I'm not even using it. Don't even remember why I had put it in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this, because what you pass to `date()` is the format you want to display it in. `date()` is the function you call in order to format a date.

So you can't store the result and use it again, because the result is a human-readable string which is hard to translate back into an internal date representation. What you're doing is already the easiest (and really, the only) way to do it, and also will have minimal impact on your performance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways.

1. Get a timestamp with `time()` store it in variable and call date('YOUR_FORMAT', $timestamp);
2. Use class [\DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and use method `format()` on the datetime object

Those two options have this advantage that datetime will be always the same and it won't change because of slow execution of the code.